Is the variance formula for error propagation useful when f is not normally distributed?
I make n measurements of different properties. E.g. the weight and the volume of an object (n=2).
Since there are uncertainties in the measurements I model this as
n independent random variables $X_i$ that are normally distributed with unknown $\mu_i$. However the uncertainity is determined by my apparatus. For instance my weight may only measure down to grams.
In this case I would say that the uncertainty is $\pm 0.5 g$.
I therefore would assume that $\sigma_i = 0.25 g$ in this case since this would mean that with 95 % confidence
$$ 
\mu_i - 2\sigma_i <= xi <= \mu_i + 2\sigma_i
$$
where $\mu_i$ is the actual weight and $x_i$ is the measured weight.
I have a function f that is a nonlinear combination of $X_i$.
E.g. $f=density = weight/volume$.
The variance formulae (1) states that:
$$
\sigma_f^2 \approx \Sigma_{i=1}^N (\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_i}\sigma_i)^2 
$$
provided that the Taylor expansion of f converges.
However since f generally is not a normal distribution how useful is $\sigma_f$?
Sure I can find the range:
$$
-2\sigma_f <= f <= 2\sigma_f
$$
but I do not know if this a 95 % or 5% confidence interval.
1 Propagation of uncertainty

There must be typos in your formula, because the right hand side easily can be negative, regardless of how nice the Taylor expansion is.  The CI formulas are also missing some terms.  Moreover, since you know the distributions of the $X_i,$ computing a confidence interval is pointless (and meaningless: what property would it represent?).  Are you sure you are asking about confidence intervals?

Xi are variabels I measure. I want to find a bounds for f that takes into account the uncertainty in these measurements: fmin <= f <= fmax.  Since an absolute bound is impossible I seek a 95 % confidence interval.

A confidence interval is an interval for a population parameter.  If you require an interval for a an unobserved value (say a future value), or an interval for some substantial fraction of the population, neither of those are confidence intervals. If you really do want a confidence interval, what parameter do you require an interval for?
